# How to reference and use images downloaded with Phonegap from application?

Tags: javascript, ios, html, cordova

I used Phonegap File API to download to an external app (external to www folder) folder a lot of images. Now, I need to reference these images in order to show them in my application in my img tags. But when I try to reference the image source as "file:///users/..../myimage.jpg" I see that not works.

What is way to reference and use the images downloaded with phonegap from my Application? I readed that the file protocol isn't enabled and that isn't possible download the images to inside a www folder.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is something to do with how many sub folders can be traversed. Im currently looking into a similar problem, and this is my early explanation. Are your image in sub-folders of folders? Try moving them so they are only 1 folder down eg: root/img/image.gif